# Using {targets} and {box}

Tags: r, targets-r-package, r-box

What would be the best way to use {targets} but writing all the functions using {box}?

The problems I am facing are mainly that it is verbose to "source" the functions in my module (box::use() instead of tar_source()) and any alteration in the code of a module, even if it doesn't change a function, makes all targets outdated.

Comment: Unfortunately ‘targets’ currently doesn’t support this, see https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/936. Solving this is definitely on my list of things to do, but won’t be easy.